# Efficient way of replacing values from a data set with values from another one

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    if df['budget'].iloc[index] == 0:
        if df['production_companies'].iloc[index] == df1['production_companies'].iloc[index1]
            and df['release_date'].iloc[index].year == df1['release_year'].iloc[index1] :
                df['budget'].iloc[index] = df1['mean'].iloc[index1]
```

It works, but it would take too long to finish. How can I make it run faster?
I also tried:

```
df.where((df['budget'] != 0 and df['production_companies'] != df1['production_companies']
    and df['release_date'] != df1['release_year']),
        other = pd.replace(to_replace = df['budget'],
            value = df1['mean'],  inplace = True))
```

It should be faster but it doesn't work. How do I achieve this?
Thank you!

`df` looks like this:

```
budget; production_companies;   release_date    ;title    
0;  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy ;10/21/1988;    Ariel    
0;  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy ;10/16/1986;    Shadows in Paradise   
4000000;    Miramax Films;  12/25/1995; Four Rooms   
0;  Universal Pictures; 10/15/1993; Judgment Night   
42000;  inLoops ;1/1/2006;  Life in Loops (A Megacities RMX)   
...
```

and `df1`:

```
production_companies;   release_year;   mean;
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM);  1998;   17500000    
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM);  1999;   12500000   
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM);  2000;   12000000   
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)   ;2001   ;43500000  
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM);  2002    ;12000000  
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)   ;2003;  36000000  
Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM);  2004    ;27500000   
...
```

I want to replace the value 0 from `df` with the "mean" vealue from `df1` if the year and the production company is the same.

Comment: Some sample input data and expected output would greatly aid in us helping you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use loops for this task**

The main benefit of pandas is vectorised functionality.

One way to vectorise your calculation is by aligning indices and then using `pd.DataFrame.index.map`. To extract year, you need to convert to `datetime` first.

Data from @ALollz.

```
# convert release_date to datetime and calculate year
df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'])
df['year'] = df['release_date'].dt.year

# create mapping from df1
s = df1.set_index(['production_companies', 'release_year'])['mean']

# use map on selected condition
mask = df['budget'] == 0
df.loc[mask, 'budget'] = df[mask].set_index(['production_company', 'year']).index.map(s.get)

print(df)

#      budget           production_company release_date title  year
# 0   1000000  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1988-10-21   AAA  1988
# 1       100  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1986-10-18   BBB  1986
# 2  30000000  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1955-12-25   CCC  1955
# 3      1000                Miramax Films   2006-01-01   DDD  2006
# 4   5000000                Miramax Films   2017-04-13   EEE  2017
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all of the loops, you can accomplish this efficiently with a merge. Here I provided some example data, since none of the data you provided will actually merge. You want to make sure `release_date` in `df` is a datetime, if it isn't already.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'budget': [0, 100, 0, 1000, 0],
                   'production_company': ['Villealfa Filmproduction Oy', 'Villealfa Filmproduction Oy',
                                      'Villealfa Filmproduction Oy', 'Miramax Films', 'Miramax Films'],
                   'release_date': ['10/21/1988', '10/18/1986', '12/25/1955', '1/1/2006', '4/13/2017'],
                   'title': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'production_companies': ['Villealfa Filmproduction Oy', 'Villealfa Filmproduction Oy', 
    'Villealfa Filmproduction Oy', 'Miramax Films', 'Miramax Films'],
                'release_year': [1988, 1986, 1955, 2006, 2017],
                   'mean': [1000000, 2000000, 30000000, 4000000, 5000000]})

df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.release_date, format='%m/%d/%Y')

#   budget           production_company release_date title
#0       0  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1988-10-21   AAA
#1     100  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1986-10-18   BBB
#2       0  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1955-12-25   CCC
#3    1000                Miramax Films   2006-01-01   DDD
#4       0                Miramax Films   2017-04-13   EEE
```

Then you want to replace budget where it is 0 with the mean if production company and year match. So as a merge this is:

```
df.loc[df.budget==0, 'budget'] = (df.merge(df1, left_on=['production_company', 
    df.release_date.dt.year], right_on=['production_companies', 'release_year'], how='left')
    .loc[df.budget==0, 'mean'])

#     budget           production_company release_date title
#0   1000000  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1988-10-21   AAA
#1       100  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1986-10-18   BBB
#2  30000000  Villealfa Filmproduction Oy   1955-12-25   CCC
#3      1000                Miramax Films   2006-01-01   DDD
#4   5000000                Miramax Films   2017-04-13   EEE
```

If you don't have `mean` data for a given production company and year, the `0`s in `budget` will be replaced with `np.NaN`, so you can either leave them or replace them back to 0 if you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly remove one cycle by using your if statement earlier:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if df['budget'].iloc[index] == 0:
      for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        if df['production_companies'].iloc[index] == df1['production_companies'].iloc[index1] and df['release_date'].iloc[index].year == df1['release_year'].iloc[index1] :
            df['budget'].iloc[index] = df1['mean'].iloc[index1]
```